# How to install nginx-module-brotli?

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, compression, make

I have a server with ubuntu 20.04

But I am unable to install `nginx-module-brotli` for my nginx server.

Here are the commands I use to install Brotli for Nginx :

```
$ sudo apt install git gcc cmake libpcre3 libpcre3-dev zlib1g zlib1g-dev openssl libssl-dev
$ wget https://nginx.org/download/nginx-1.18.0.tar.gz
$ tar zxvf nginx-1.18.0.tar.gz
$ git clone https://github.com/google/ngx_brotli.git
$ cd ~/ngx_brotli
$ git submodule update --init
$ cd ~/nginx-1.18.0
$ ./configure --with-compat --add-dynamic-module=../ngx_brotli
$ make modules
$ sudo cp ./objs/*.so /usr/share/nginx/modules
$ cd
```

and

```
$ sudo nano /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

load_module modules/ngx_http_brotli_filter_module.so;
load_module modules/ngx_http_brotli_static_module.so;

ubuntu@ov-ert6:~$ sudo systemctl restart nginx

ubuntu@ov-ert6:~$ sudo nginx -t
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
```

When I test my site, it cannot find Brotli in the headers :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0YW8u.png)

```
ubuntu@ov-ert6:~$ sudo cat /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

load_module modules/ngx_http_brotli_filter_module.so;
load_module modules/ngx_http_brotli_static_module.so;
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # server_tokens off;

    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # SSL Settings
    ##

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;

    # gzip_vary on;
    # gzip_proxied any;
    # gzip_comp_level 6;
    # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    # gzip_http_version 1.1;
    # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}


#mail {
#   # See sample authentication script at:
#   # http://wiki.nginx.org/ImapAuthenticateWithApachePhpScript
# 
#   # auth_http localhost/auth.php;
#   # pop3_capabilities "TOP" "USER";
#   # imap_capabilities "IMAP4rev1" "UIDPLUS";
# 
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:110;
#       protocol   pop3;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
# 
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:143;
#       protocol   imap;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
#}
```

and

```
sudo nano /etc/nginx/sites-available/www-example-com.conf

server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name example.com;

    location / {
        return 301 http://www.example.com$request_uri;
    }
}

server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name www.example.com;
    root /var/www/www-example-com/web;
    index index.php;

    #add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
    #add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";
    add_header Referrer-Policy "strict-origin";
    add_header Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https: data:; base-uri 'self';";
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload";
    add_header Feature-Policy "speaker 'none';";

    gzip on;
    gzip_vary on;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_comp_level 6;
    gzip_types text/plain text/css text/xml application/json application/javascript application/xml+rss application/atom+xml image/svg+xml;

    brotli on;
    brotli_comp_level 6;
    brotli_types text/plain text/css text/xml application/json application/javascript application/xml+rss application/atom+xml image/svg+xml;
}
```

Comment: Hm, OK. This problem sounds like that the previous `./configure` command did not actually succeed. Check the log on screen and the `config.log` file for any possible clues.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I have no more errors, but Brotli does not work.

Comment: Did you make sure that the self compiled Nginx version is used (and not the Nginx version from the Ubuntu repos)?

Comment: How are you checking that `brotli` is not enabled? What is the output of `nginx -t` and `nginx -T`?

Comment: @TeroKilkanen Here is the result of the command `nginx -T` https://pastebin.com/PAHQVmHS

Comment: @HenrikPingel I don't know I did `sudo apt install nginx` and I did the instructions in the question

Comment: Since `nginx -T` shows no errors, it means that the `brotli` module is loaded correctly. What is the output of `curl -v -H 'Accept-Encoding: br' http://example.com`, where `example.com` is your website?

Comment: @TeroKilkanen https://pastebin.com/Tek9HBUq on this site it is written that it is not supported https://tools.keycdn.com/brotli-test

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to run your site on top of HTTPS. Brotli doesn't support http protocol. Further information can be found in https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/11/better-than-gzip-compression-with-brotli/

Comment: Super it works in https thank you